# How do I show that two groups are not isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that the additive groups of $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ are not isomorphic.

It is hard to create a map that will show homomorphism.

Answer (score 6):

Every homomorphism of $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Q$ is determined by $f(1)$. It follows  that there is no surjective homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Prove that $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic (try proof by contradiction) and show that being cyclic is invariant under isomorphisms.

Comment: That is a good idea thanks